# Transforming XML into HTML with couple representations

Tags: xslt

My XML contains description of some resource. I want to build HTML with JSON, XML, etc. representation of this resource.

Here is XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <resource name="item">
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="id">
                <example-value>1234</example-value>
                <type>integer</type>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="name">
                <example-value>parameter</example-value>
                <type>string</type>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="timestamp">
                <example-value>1466589751</example-value>
                <type>integer</type>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="status">
                <example-value>1</example-value>
                <type>integer</type>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

And here is how I do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="resources">
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="resource">
        <div>
            <h2>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="parameters">
        <h3>
            <xsl:text>Examples</xsl:text>
        </h3>
        <div>
            <xsl:call-template name="CSVExample"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="TableExample"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="JSONExample"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="XMLExample"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="CSVExample">
        <div>
            <pre>
                <xsl:for-each select="parameter">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',@name,'&quot;')"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:for-each select="parameter">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',example-value,'&quot;')"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </pre>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="TableExample">
        <div>
            <pre>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="parameter">
                            <th>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                            </th>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="parameter">
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="example-value"/>
                            </td>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </pre>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="JSONExample">
        <div>
            <pre>
                <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
                <xsl:for-each select="parameter">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',@name,'&quot;:')"/>
                    <xsl:if test="type = 'string'">
                        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="example-value"/>
                    <xsl:if test="type = 'string'">
                        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
            </pre>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="XMLExample">
        <div>
            <pre>
                <parameters>
                    <xsl:for-each select="parameter">
                        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="example-value"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </parameters>
            </pre>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do You think this is right way to do such a case? I mean templates structure, calls, applys, etc.
Should I mayby replace for-each with some apply-templates? I read somewhere that is better to avoid for-each in favour of apply-templates. But is that true in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure we could discuss many alternative ways to rework your xsl but to be honest this is not the correct forum for such things -- You really ought to be using that code review forum on Stack Exchange.

That said, I think your xsl structure is generally good - better than most we see on this site!

However, as it stands if <parameters> exits without any child <<parameter> nodes the call-templates wil still generate unwanted(?) content.

You would be better to use apply-templates with a mode attribute.

```
<xsl:template match="properties" mode="CSVExample">
....
</xsl:template>
```

and replace the call-templates with

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="CSVExample"/>
```

As for deciding betwee the for-each or apply-templates :   When using a select="", I dont think it generally matters which way you go.  Personally, I opt for apply-templates every time, it's more flexible and only use for-each whenever the code looks neater or is easier to understand that way.